# Using For Loop to Call the Same Named Functions from Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to see if it's possible to click a button on a series of sheets with a function. For a single sheet, my code works fine, but I get an Runtime error 438 when I try to do the code below.

```
Public Sub Read_All_Data_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Read_Data_Click

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ws is defined as worksheet, during the for loop the variable will be updated to be the current worksheet. Because of this using Sheets(ws.name) is redundant, instead your code should look like:

```
Public Sub Read_All_Data_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

ws.Read_Data_Click

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Read_Data_Click is not a built in property of a worksheet.

You have to write your Sub Read_Data_Click(MySheet as worksheet) in a module, and parse the referance to each wc from the loop. Then you only use the name of the sub like Read_Data_Click(ws)